# How to be able to define variable with a class?

Tags: powershell

Let's say I want to make a class like so:

```
class myClass {
  [string]$test
  myClass(
    [string]$myString
  ){
    $this.test = $myString
  }
}
```

I can define variables with that class with

```
$var = [myClass]::new("Test")
```

Which would make variable `var` equal to

```
test
----
Test
```

How could I make this a single string like `test` so I can define a variable like

```
[myClass]$var = "Test"
```

And have the variabe equal to

```
Test
```

Instead of

```
test
----
Test
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a variable that is creating a new instance of myClass. So it is also a property. And when you display $var, you see the properties are formatted as table as you see other objects formatted by default. But you can display so like:

```
$var | Select-Object -ExpandProperty test
```

Output:

```
Test
```

Comment: Is not what I want. I want to define a class and by default not have it in a table but just a single value

Answer (score 0):

Well. How about `$var = ([myClass]::new("Test")).test` ?
Quite dirty but does the job...